# pyopengl glGenVertexArrays() causes segfault in threads

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pyopengl

Working on a basic minecraft imitation in python using opengl, specifically  the pyopengl python module. Found that updating world geometry in the main thread was talking too long, so I decided to make a thread to do it(using the `threading` library). Before this, `glGenVertexArrays()` was working fine.

However, after I starting a thread to do the same function, it started returning this:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I tracked the problem down to this* line in my Mesh objects `__init__` method, which was being called by the thread to make more geometry(another chunk).

Thread code:

```
    def update(self): ## Just to make new chunks and set their visibility based on player position 
        global RUNNING
        while RUNNING == True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            player_chunk_pos = self.player.position.tolist()
            player_chunk_pos = [int(player_chunk_pos[0] // (Chunk.size[0] * Block.size)), int(player_chunk_pos[2] // (Chunk.size[1] * Block.size))]
            if player_chunk_pos != self.player.chunk_pos:
                print("Changed Chunks")
                self.player.chunk_pos = player_chunk_pos
                print("Passed 1")
                self.make_or_use() ## method that calls the __init__() method
```

the self.make_or_use calls another function which eventually calls the `__init__` function for the Mesh object:

Mesh-making code:

```
    def __init__(self, verticies):

        self.verticies = verticies

        self.vertex_count = len(self.verticies) // 8 # find the number of vertexes. 8 is the number of attributes in the dataset

        self.verticies = np.array(self.verticies, dtype=np.float32)

        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1) #### * THIS LINE ############

        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        self.vbo = glGenBuffers(1) 
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)  
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.verticies.nbytes, self.verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW) 

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, ctypes.c_void_p(12))

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, ctypes.c_void_p(20))
```

Any ideas on why this is happening, how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid and "current" [OpenGL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) to call an OpenGL API function. If you do not have a current context, this will result in a segfault. However, the OpenGL context is local to a thread. If you want to call an OpenGL function from another thread, you must make the OpenGL Context current in that thread. Unfortunately, an OpenGL Context can only be current in one thread at a time. Making it current in a thread will release it in the thread where it was previously current. So you cannot update the VAO from one thread while another thread is using the same OpenGL context. You need to use 2 shared OpenGL contexts for your task.

---

Minimal example with shared OpenGL Contexts:

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import OpenGL.GL.shaders
import glfw
import time
import threading
import ctypes

sh_vert = """
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 a_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 a_uv;
out vec2 uv;

void main() 
{
    uv = a_uv;
    gl_Position = a_position;
}
"""

sh_frag = """
#version 460 core

out vec4 frag_color;
in vec2 uv;

void main() 
{
    frag_color = vec4(1.0-uv.x, 1.0-uv.y, uv.x*uv.y, 1.0);
}
"""

if glfw.init() == glfw.FALSE:
    exit()

loaded_lock = threading.Lock()
terminate_load_thread_event = threading.Event()
def load_thread_function():
    global vbo, ebo, program

    loaded_lock.acquire()
    glfw.make_context_current(load_window)

    attributes = (GLfloat * 20)(*[-1,-1,0,0,1, 1,-1,0,1,1, 1,1,0,1,0, -1,1,0,0,0])
    indices = (GLuint * 6)(*[0,1,2, 0,2,3])

    default_vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
    vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
    ebo = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindVertexArray(default_vao)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, attributes, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    program = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(
        OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(sh_vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
        OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(sh_frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    )

    loaded_lock.release()

    while not glfw.window_should_close(load_window) and not terminate_load_thread_event.wait(0.01):
        glfw.swap_buffers(load_window)
        glfw.poll_events()
    print("terminate load thread")

glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, glfw.FALSE)
load_window = glfw.create_window(400, 400, "OpenGL load Window", None, None)
#glfw.make_context_current(load_window)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, glfw.TRUE)
window = glfw.create_window(400, 400, "OpenGL Window", None, load_window)
glfw.make_context_current(window)

load_thread = threading.Thread(target=load_thread_function)
load_thread.start()
loaded_lock.acquire()

vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
glBindVertexArray(vao)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 5 * 4, None)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 5 * 4, ctypes.c_void_p(3 * 4))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

glUseProgram(program)

while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
   
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.poll_events()

terminate_load_thread_event.set()
load_thread.join()
print("terminate")

glfw.terminate()
exit()
```